# Azure - authenticate a console app using alternative to MSI

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, console-application, azure-keyvault

I'm working on a solution that currently runs code in Azure Functions.  These functions are authenticated to our PaaS services (Key Vault/Service Bus/Blob Storage etc) using MSI authentication.

The code to authenticate is then as follows:

```
// Connect to KeyVault in the context of the running code.
var tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddAzureKeyVault(
     keyvaultUri,
     new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(tokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback)),
     new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager())
  .Build();
```

This then allows me to connect to securely to Service Bus using code like this:

```
// Get ServiceBus connection settings.
config.GetSection("Messaging").Bind(ConfigSettings);    
var namespaceName = Regex.Match(ConfigSettings.ConnectionString, @"Endpoint=sb:\/\/([^.]*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;


var token = tokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", string.Empty).Result;
var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(token);

var client = RestClient.Configure()
        .WithEnvironment(AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)
        .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
        .WithCredentials(new AzureCredentials(tokenCredentials, tokenCredentials, string.Empty, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud))
    .Build();

// Authenticate against Service Bus.
ServiceBusNamespace = Azure.Authenticate(client, string.Empty)
    .WithSubscription(ConfigSettings.SubscriptionId)
    .ServiceBusNamespaces.List()
    .SingleOrDefault(n => n.Name == namespaceName);
```

We are changing our solution so that instead of running Functions on ASE, we are going to carry out the same operation in a Console App (running on Linux).  Obviously MSI auth won't work in this scenario, so I was looking to use a Service Priniple AppId and AppSercret.  I setup the Principle in AAD as follows:

[image]

That code to utilise this Service Principles AppId and AppSecret is as follows:

```
    public async static Task<string> GetAccessToken(string tenantId, string appId, string appSecret)
    {
        var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.windows.net/{tenantId}");
        var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: appId, clientSecret: appSecret);
        var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource: "https://management.core.windows.net/", clientCredential: credential);

        if (result == null) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
        }

        return result.AccessToken;    
     }
```

BUT it requires me to hold the likes of the AppId, AppSecret and TenantId ready for the app to use.  I don't want to use AppSettings for obvious security reasons.

I can now run the Service Bus authentication using similar code to what I had before:

```
    var namespaceName = Regex.Match(connectionString, @"Endpoint=sb:\/\/([^.]*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;

    var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(token);

    var client = RestClient.Configure()
        .WithEnvironment(AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)
        .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
        .WithCredentials(new AzureCredentials(tokenCredentials, tokenCredentials, string.Empty, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud))
        .Build();

    var serviceBusNamespace = Azure.Authenticate(client, string.Empty)
        .WithSubscription(subscriptionId)
        .ServiceBusNamespaces.List()
        .SingleOrDefault(n => n.Name == namespaceName);

    if (serviceBusNamespace == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Couldn't find the service bus namespace {namespaceName} in the subscription with ID {subscriptionId}");
    }
```

My question - it seems counter productive to worry about security and then store the required config fields (AppId, AppSecret, TenantId) in config or Env Vars.  Do I have any other options?  I cant use KeyVault unless I have authenticated but again, I need my Service Principle authenticated before I can access it.

Has anyone made this approach before?  Maybe Service Principle isn't the right approach?

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: Are you sure you can't use MSI? Ultimately it uses an HTTP endpoint accessible from the runtime environment (which you should be able to use from Linux too :) )

Comment: Actually no, im not! Im just used to configuing it via the ASE and not in code. Any good examples? I couldnt see specific examples of code to authenticate using msi from a console app, unfortunately

Comment: This looks promising: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/resources/samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-dotnet/

Comment: You can also check out my article on MSI: https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-managed-service-identity. I mention the two environment variables that it uses under the hood. Of course the problem is you need to get those environment variables.. And I am not sure your console app can get them.

Comment: Thanks Joonas, so if I set the two environment variables of MSI_ENDPOINT and MSI_SECRET, and run those couple of lines of code it will still work for the console app?  Neat!  Where do I get the MSI_ENDPOINT and MSI_SECRET from? (I didn't set this up originally) - thanks!!!

Comment: Well.. I don't think it'll work if you set them. MSI sets them and uses the secret to authenticate to the endpoint.

Comment: Not sure how to get your example going then if they need to be in the ENV VARS for the app and I cant set them :-)  thanks anyway

Comment: MSI sets them, so if they are visible you can use it. If they aren't then you can't use it and have to use app settings to bootstrap the authentication.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you do not want to store `AppId` in config file and want use `Service Principle` to authenticate.

If so, you could refer to the juunas article and you could use `AzureServiceTokenProvider` to authenticate and go on what you want.

You could use the following code to get key vault secret without using `AppId` and `AppSecret`.

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

var scret = keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync("https://xxxx.vault.azure.net", "xxxx").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: The app will be running on Linux, not on ASE where we can set the app to run under the Service Principle context.  So, to get that context, I need the Service Principles AppID/AppSecret to authenticate as that principle when the code is executing - or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Yes, you need to get the AppId and AppSecret to authenticate, so what do you doubt about?

Comment: I doubt the code you've shown - as you aren't setting AppId/AppSecret in code, it will then rely on the context it's run (AzureServiceTokenProvider()).  Which wont work when we take the app out of ASE.

Comment: Yes, so you want to find a way to get authenticate on linux right?

Comment: Yea that's it @joey-cai I was thinking Service Principle was the way to go.  I've Azure WebJob off ASE and into a console app (.net core) that I will be deploying to Linux but don't want to lose the security that's baked into ASE.